# Code 500 after posting a JSON?

Tags: json, cakephp

I'm trying Post a JSON using Postman of Chrome. JSON is `{"email":"myself@gmail.com"}`. When I send doesn't works and throws an exception Code:500. 
Look at in `app/tmp/logs/error.log` I found the problem, but I don't know how could I solve it.

**Exception**

```
2015-08-16 01:06:43 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "Users\json\show_post_json.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'Users\\json\\show_post_json.ctp',
)
Request URL: /PainelEscolar/users/showPostJson.json
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PainelEscolar\lib\Cake\View\JsonView.php(107): View->_getViewFileName(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PainelEscolar\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(960): JsonView->render(NULL, NULL)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PainelEscolar\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(200): Controller->render()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PainelEscolar\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\PainelEscolar\app\webroot\index.php(118): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

**PHP Function**

```
//URL: http://localhost/PainelEscolar/users/showPostJson.json
public function showPostJson(){              
            $data = $this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));
            echo $data["email"];            
        }
```

Comment: Try return after you echo. It will be trying to load the template for that method. Also could try $this->render(false) - it's been a while since I used cakephp

Comment: I did `$this->autoRender = false;` before `$data` and works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Great - I'll write you up an answer not that I'm not on a mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controller thinks that `showPostJson` is a view, so is trying to find a view file to render.

Since you're just outputting JSON from it, you could prevent it from trying to load a view using `$this->render(false)` - and you might also want to use the [inbuilt AJAX layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts):

```
public function showPostJson() {
    $this->render(false);
    $this->layout = 'ajax'

    $data = $this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));
    echo $data["email"];
}
```